# zf create action under a module controller is not working

Tags: php, zend-framework

I tried to create an action in a controller class under a module through zf command line tool. but it giving an error

My command:
**zf create action abc login 1 admin**

```
An Error Has Occurred
A project profile was not found.

Zend Framework Command Line Console Tool v1.11.11
Details for action "Create" and provider "Action"
Action
zf create action name controller-name[=Index] view-included[=1] module
```

Also i tried it manually then its working.

my URL look like this: **[projectname]/admin/login/abc**

how to solve and what will be the reason please help me.

Comment: Make sure where you typing this command ? That directory should have zf.sh file in it. Or create an alis for it

Comment: Rikesh how can i create zf alias in my project?